# Inserting IF statements - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I keep coming across this problem, where i want to insert an IF statement into my class, but keeps returning an illegal start of type/expression error.

Is there something im doing wrong here, if so could somebody point me in the direction of where i should be puting these IF statements.

I need an IF statement like:

```
IF (RList.contains(r1.getRouteName() == "Route2"))
c1.setCollision1(b1.getStartTime ++ c1.getCollision1)

ELSE
c1.setCollision2(b1.getStartTime ++ c1.getCollision2)
```

I know that is more than likely wrong, but anyway. 
I want to insert that piece of code into the following  class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Student s2 = new Student();
        Booking b1 = new Booking();
        Route r1 = new Route();
        Route r2 = new Route();
        Examiner e1 = new Examiner();
        Examiner e2 = new Examiner();
        Collision c1 = new Collision();

        //New Student

        s2.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID for Student 2: [0001]")));
        s2.setFname(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name of Student 2: "));
        s2.setLname(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last name of Student 2: "));
        s2.setAddress(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address for Student 2: "));
        s2.setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter phone number for Student 2: "));
        s2.setOtherDetails(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter other details for Student 2: "));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Student Two: \n" + s2.toString());

       //End of New Student

       //New Booking

        b1.setBookingId(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID for Booking 1: [0001]")));
        b1.setBookingType(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Booking Type for Booking 1: [Exam or Lesson]"));
        b1.setStartTime(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("EnterStart time for Booking 1: ")));
        b1.setEndTime(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address for Student 2: ")));
        b1.setBookingDate(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Date for Booking 1: [01-JAN-2012]"));
        b1.setHistory(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of previous examiner 2: [enter 'null' if no previous]"));


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Booking One: \n" + b1.toString());

        //End of New Booking

        //Set the Routes

        r1.setRouteId(0001);
        r1.setRouteName("Route1");
        r1.setEndTime(0.40);

        r2.setRouteId(0002);
        r2.setRouteName("Route2");
        r2.setEndTime(0.50);

        //End Set Routes

        //Create Examiners

        e1.setExaminerId(0001);
        e1.setName("John Murphy");
        e1.setOtherDetails("ADI Registered");

        e2.setExaminerId(0002);
        e2.setName("Lucy Casey");
        e2.setOtherDetails("ADI Registered");

        //End Create Examiners

 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Connect to database and insert data into database">


       String strConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.staff.ittralee.ie:1521:orcl"; 
       String strUser = "*"; 
       String strPassword = "*"; 

       try { 
        Driver drv = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver(); 
        DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strConn, strUser, strPassword); 
        //code to execute commands... 

// </editor-fold>

        //StudentInsert

        String query = "INSERT INTO Student(STUDENTID, FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS, " + 
        "PHONENO, OTHERDETAILS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
        pstmt.setInt(1, s2.getStudentId()); 
        pstmt.setString(2, s2.getFname()); 
        pstmt.setString(3, s2.getLname()); 
        pstmt.setString(4, s2.getAddress()); 
        pstmt.setString(5, s2.getPhoneNo()); 
        pstmt.setString(6, s2.getOtherDetails()); 
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        //End Student Insert

        //Booking Insert

        String query1 = "INSERT INTO Booking(BOOKINGID, BOOKINGTYPE, LNAME, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, " +
        "BOOKINGDATE, HISTORY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        pstmt1.setInt(1, b1.getBookingId());
        pstmt1.setString(2, b1.getBookingType());
        pstmt1.setDouble(3, b1.getStartTime());
        pstmt1.setDouble(4, b1.getEndTime());
        pstmt1.setString(5, b1.getBookingDate());
        pstmt1.setString(6, b1.getHistory());
        pstmt1.executeUpdate();

        //End Booking Insert

        //Returns Id of route not in use

        String query2 = "SELECT R.RouteID FROM Route R WHERE RouteID not in (SELECT B.RouteId FROM Booking B)";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, query2);

        //End Route not in use

        //Adding routes to a list to randomly assign an examiner to a route

        LinkedList< String> EList = new LinkedList< String>();

        EList.add(e1.getName());
        EList.add(e2.getName());
        Collections.shuffle(EList);

        LinkedList< String> RList = new LinkedList< String>();

        RList.add(r1.getRouteName());
        RList.add(r2.getRouteName());
        Collections.shuffle(RList);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Examiner: " + EList + "\nRoute: " + RList);

        //End random assign route



        } 

       catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
    }





    }


}
```

Comment: your if syntax is incorrect. Have you checked a reference manual about it?

Comment: The problem with your sample input is that the `==` shouldn't be in the if statement. That returns a boolean value, which, even if this was syntactically correct, would not be accepted into the `contains()`  method.

Comment: I know all that if statement is wrong i wrote it as a quick sample. But what i am saying is even a basic if statement like a 2 + 2 = 4 with an output still returns the same error

Comment: `if((2+2) == 4) { /*Do Something*/ }` will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong

```
IF (RList.contains(r1.getRouteName() == "Route2"))
c1.setCollision1(b1.getStartTime ++ c1.getCollision1)

ELSE
c1.setCollision2(b1.getStartTime ++ c1.getCollision2)
```

It should look like this

```
if (RList.contains(r1.getRouteName() == "Route2")) {
    c1.setCollision1(b1.getStartTime + c1.getCollision1);
}
else {
    c1.setCollision2(b1.getStartTime + c1.getCollision2);
}
```

Also

`RList.contains(r1.getRouteName() == "Route2")`

won't work the way you want it to. First off `Strings` should be compared using `equals` rather than `==` as in

`r1.getRouteName().equals("Route2")`.

Secondly what this will do if check if `RList` contains the value `true` or `false` depending on the result of the `r1.getRouteName().equals("Route2")`. I think this might actually cause an compiler error.

If you want to determine whether `RList` includes r1 and r1's Route name is Route2 you'll have to do this.

```
if(RList.contains(r1) && r1.getRouteName().equals("Route2"))
```

Note this will compare with case sensitivity on for case insensitivity use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals`

Comment: Thank you for correcting that, but I know all that if statement is wrong anyway i wrote it as a quick sample. But what i am saying is even a basic if statement like a 2 + 2 = 4 with an output still returns the same error

Comment: What does the if statement 2+2 = 4 look like? it should look like the one I wrote in response to your other comment.

Comment: Also perhaps be a little safer .toLower() to avoid any case sensitivity issues.

Comment: @GrahamSmith case sensitivity might be desired but if it isn't i would recommend `equalsIgnoreCase()` since Java already provides it.

Answer (score 3):

If statements should be in lower case:

```
if(RList.contains(r1.getRouteName() == "Route2"))
    c1.setCollision1(b1.getStartTime + c1.getCollision1)

else
    c1.setCollision2(b1.getStartTime + c1.getCollision2)
```

Comment: what about those double plus signs in there?

Comment: In the predicate, I think the intended logic is:

`if(RList.contains("Route2".equals(r1.getRouteName())))
`


Though the semantics seem to be flawed.

Comment: i have no idea what he's trying to do there... :S

Comment: Forget the if statement haha. I didnt intend for it to be corrected, it was a sample. All i want to know is where in my code can i put An if statement without an error, because everywhere ive tried just isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out whether a particular String value is in the linked list ? If you are, then this syntax should do the job:

```
LinkedList<String> routeList = new LinkedList<String>();
routeList.add("Route 1");
routeList.add("Route 2");
Collections.shuffle(routeList);
if (routeList.contains("Route 1")) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use == operator to compare two strings, using == operators u can only compare numerical value, try to use equal() method in order to compare two different String.

Comment: that's not completely accurate. You can use == to compare `Objects` but it compares whether or not the `Objects` point to the same data not whether they're values are equal. Also == is used for all primitives not just numerical so `chars` and `booleans` use ==